# ActionColumn renderer function sometimes not fired

Tags: extjs, grid, renderer

I have a grid with a RowWidget plugin that adds the ability to have a second row body which expands/contracts and which contains a Component.

```
columns: [{
        itemId: 'checkNameId',
        text: 'Check Name',
        dataIndex: 'shortName',
        align: 'left',
        flex: 1
    }],

    plugins: {
        ptype: 'rowwidget',
        widget: {
            xtype: 'grid',     
            bind: { store: '{record.taskEntities}' },
            autoLoad: false,

            columns: [{
                itemId: 'resultKeyId',
                text: 'Result Key',
                dataIndex: 'resultKey',
                flex: 1,
                align: 'left'
            }, {
                text: 'Exclusions',
                itemId: 'exclusionId',
                columns: [{
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    itemId: 'addExclusionId',
                    text: 'Add',
                    align: 'center',
                    flex: 1,
                    renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
                        if (record.data.exclusion != null) {
                            meta.style = 'visibility: hidden';
                        }
                    },
                    items: [{
                        iconCls: 'x-fa fa-plus-circle',
                        handler: 'clickOnExclusionAdd'
                    }]
                }, {
                    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
                    itemId: 'editExclusionId',
                    text: 'Edit',
                    align: 'center',
                    flex: 1,
                    renderer: function (value, meta, record) {
                        if (record.data.exclusion == null) {
                            meta.style = 'visibility: hidden';
                        }
                    },
                    items: [{
                        iconCls: 'pictos pictos-pencil',
                        handler: 'clickOnExclusionEdit'
                    }]
                }]
            }],
        }
    }
```

The problem is, that sometimes the renderer function not fired and i dont know why. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong.
Its a sencha classic application with the version 7.0.0.

Comment: I created a https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/32s8 with your example, but everything works in it. Сould you substitute your data in it or edit it to see the bug?

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. In the normal case it works for me as in her fiddle. Only sometimes (especially in Firefox) the renderer event is not fired. Then the add and edit columns are completely white. When debugging, I found that the renderer event is not fired. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the error.